# Serializing a hierarchy of plain C# objects to a JSON array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I have a class structure in C#, similar to the following:

```
[DataContract]
class Data
{
    [DataMember] public List<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

[DataContract]
class Hotel
{
    [DataMember] public int HotelID { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string HotelName { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

I've been serializing this to JSON, using the 'DataContractJsonSerializer'.

However, because JSON includes all the property names, this makes for a  lot of redundant text.

(You might say gZip alleviates this, but I believe gZip compresses only a portion of the output, like the first n kilobytes, so in this case, it's not really going to help.)

So what I'd prefer to do is spit out the data in the format of a Javascript array, like this:

```
[[1, "firstHotel"], [2, "secondHotel"], [3, "thirdHotel"], ...]
```

Is there any way of customizing the JSON serialization to do it this way? Or should I just manually write my own serializer?

Comment: I found a format called "JSONDB" that would be pretty much ideal for this scenario: http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/json-db-a-compressed-json-format

Comment: gzip compresses everything you give it, not just the first N KB. However, it also adds a header that's not tiny.

Comment: you can write your own serializer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was attempting isn't necessary, since gzip compression will take care of the entire JSON feed, removing any redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) can handle DataContract-annotated classes.  It uses the binary Protocol Buffers format, which is smaller and faster to serialize/deserialize than JSON.  You can still dump JSON in places where you need it to be human-readable (debugging, etc.)

Even with gzip compression, the Protocol Buffers format will be smaller than JSON, though the difference in size depends on what your data looks like.